# site is running slow when php version is newer than 5.2

Tags: php, windows, php-5.2

My site had worked great untill I updated its php version to 5.4.4 (I also tryed 5.3), I can't continue using php v5.2 because I have added some function that are not supported in 5.2 version.

I work on a windows server.

Comment: how can you work with asp.net on linux? it's for windows only..

Comment: @DanBarzilay [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)

Comment: @DanBarzilay The clue is that his problem is equally as vague as yours. We can't help you unless you provide more details

Comment: I'd say you should profile with xdebug and see exactly what's taking longer, otherwise you won't find magicians here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Profile your PHP with xdebug.

You can see [PROFILING PHP WITH XDEBUG AND WEBGRIND](http://www.chrisabernethy.com/php-profiling-xdebug-webgrind/), the main parser of xdebug files (kcachegrind) is native for Linux.

An alternative is [windows port of kcachegrind](http://precompiledbin.sourceforge.net/), but I never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

XHProf is another simple tool for Profiling
It's very simple to use and configure.